# Kafka : Check if 2 topics have been caught up

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I have 2 topics in kafka which I am double writing to. Their offsets are at different commit points to begin with. My consumer starts consuming from the second topic late, but eventually will catch up with the first topic. How can I optimally find out if both of them are caught up ?

I am planning to look at a fixed window of previous messages consumed from both the topics and check if the messages consumed are similar in nature. Any ideas of how I can find if they are similar ?

Any other ideas of how I can be sure that they have been caught up ?

Also, my topic has multiple partitions. The check should include if all partitions have been caught up.

Comment: List the consumer groups given your application group id

Comment: are you writing exactly same amount of messages toboth topics? if so, sum of offsets (topic1) = sum of offsets (topic2) can give you very close results.

Answer (score 0):

From command line or using consumer api's you can calculate the consumer lag. if the lag is not significant in both the consumers, then you can safely assume that both the topics are caught up.

Also, help me understand why do you need to write the same messages to two topics. You can have multiples consumers for a topic

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate lag yourself by using the methods available here:

kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand

https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/bf237fa7c576bd141d78fdea9f17f65ea269c290/core/src/main/scala/kafka/admin/ConsumerGroupCommand.scala

There's a bit more detail in this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51749733/236528