# How to get consumer Kafka lag in java

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, lag, producer-consumer

I have a producer in java and consumer in nodeJS. I want to know in java what is the consumer lag, so i know if i can produce more data to the topic.

What is the API in java to get the consumer lag?

Comment: You can use the `kafka-consumer-groups` CLI command for a consumer group to find it

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to know the consumer lag ? The aim of a broker is to produce messages asynchronously. If you need to have a synchronous processing, use a basic rest processing.

Comment: I am using it asynchronously, I push to the kafka and the consumer pull the mesaages asynchronously. But i do want to know if the consumer can handle the amount of data i send him. If the consumer can't handle the pace the app push , the app will push in a slower pace

Comment: Kafka is aimed to manage the storage of many many events. If you slow down your producer, it will act a broker too.

Comment: I see. Byt still, is there a way to know the consumer lag?

Comment: I'm not sure spring-kafka can, I don't know for other api :(

Comment: Few solutions here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42201616/how-to-get-kafka-consume-lag-in-java-program

Comment: It's totally reasonable to know consumer lag, in case you have a malfunctioning consumer and need to find it, or to know if you need to spin up more consumers within a group.

Comment: another use case is to check if you consumers are keeping up with the produced messages

Answer (score 0):

The actual class you can call from Java is the `kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand`. It's Scala code, but it's easy to call directly from Java.

Here's a link to the Github code for perusal: https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/bf237fa7c576bd141d78fdea9f17f65ea269c290/core/src/main/scala/kafka/admin/ConsumerGroupCommand.scala

And here's the help output if you don't pass in any parameters. That should help out with the commands you need to send.

```
 
List all consumer groups, describe a consumer group, delete consumer group info, or reset consumer group offsets.
Option                                  Description                            
------                                  -----------                            
--all-topics                            Consider all topics assigned to a      
                                          group in the `reset-offsets` process.
--bootstrap-server                                                                   
--by-duration         Reset offsets to offset by duration    
                                          from current timestamp. Format:      
                                          'PnDTnHnMnS'                         
--command-config                    passed to Admin Client and Consumer. 
--delete                                Pass in groups to delete topic         
                                          partition offsets and ownership      
                                          information over the entire consumer 
                                          group. For instance --group g1 --    
                                          group g2                             
--describe                              Describe consumer group and list       
                                          offset lag (number of messages not   
                                          yet processed) related to given      
                                          group.                               
--dry-run                               Only show results without executing    
                                          changes on Consumer Groups.          
                                          Supported operations: reset-offsets. 
--execute                               Execute operation. Supported           
                                          operations: reset-offsets.           
--export                                Export operation execution to a CSV    
                                          file. Supported operations: reset-   
                                          offsets.                             
--from-file   Reset offsets to values defined in CSV 
                                          file.                                
--group         The consumer group we wish to act on.  
--list                                  List all consumer groups.              
--members                               Describe members of the group. This    
                                          option may be used with '--describe' 
                                          and '--bootstrap-server' options     
                                          only.                                
                                        Example: --bootstrap-server localhost: 
                                          9092 --describe --group group1 --    
                                          members                              
--offsets                               Describe the group and list all topic  
                                          partitions in the group along with   
                                          their offset lag. This is the        
                                          default sub-action of and may be     
                                          used with '--describe' and '--       
                                          bootstrap-server' options only.      
                                        Example: --bootstrap-server localhost: 
                                          9092 --describe --group group1 --    
                                          offsets                              
--reset-offsets                         Reset offsets of consumer group.       
                                          Supports one consumer group at the   
                                          time, and instances should be        
                                          inactive                             
                                        Has 2 execution options: --dry-run     
                                          (the default) to plan which offsets  
                                          to reset, and --execute to update    
                                          the offsets. Additionally, the --    
                                          export option is used to export the  
                                          results to a CSV format.             
                                        You must choose one of the following   
                                          reset specifications: --to-datetime, 
                                          --by-period, --to-earliest, --to-    
                                          latest, --shift-by, --from-file, --  
                                          to-current.                          
                                        To define the scope use --all-topics   
                                          or --topic. One scope must be        
                                          specified unless you use '--from-    
                                          file'.                               
--shift-by     Reset offsets shifting current offset  
                                          by 'n', where 'n' can be positive or 
                                          negative.                            
--state                                 Describe the group state. This option  
                                          may be used with '--describe' and '--
                                          bootstrap-server' options only.      
                                        Example: --bootstrap-server localhost: 
                                          9092 --describe --group group1 --    
                                          state                                
--timeout           The timeout that can be set for some   
                                          use cases. For example, it can be    
                                          used when describing the group to    
                                          specify the maximum amount of time   
                                          in milliseconds to wait before the   
                                          group stabilizes (when the group is  
                                          just created, or is going through    
                                          some changes). (default: 5000)       
--to-current                            Reset offsets to current offset.       
--to-datetime         Reset offsets to offset from datetime. 
                                          Format: 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:SS.sss'    
--to-earliest                           Reset offsets to earliest offset.      
--to-latest                             Reset offsets to latest offset.        
--to-offset               Reset offsets to a specific offset.    
--topic                  The topic whose consumer group         
                                          information should be deleted or     
                                          topic whose should be included in    
                                          the reset offset process. In `reset- 
                                          offsets` case, partitions can be     
                                          specified using this format: `topic1:
                                          0,1,2`, where 0,1,2 are the          
                                          partition to be included in the      
                                          process. Reset-offsets also supports 
                                          multiple topic inputs.               
--verbose                               Provide additional information, if     
                                          any, when describing the group. This 
                                          option may be used with '--          
                                          offsets'/'--members'/'--state' and   
                                          '--bootstrap-server' options only.   
                                        Example: --bootstrap-server localhost: 
                                          9092 --describe --group group1 --    
                                          members --verbose
```